# GET 6C6CCDBA-AFF1-E54F-A6A6-0D7A76E35801 in NGINX log

Tags: nginx, log-files

Fitrst I got notification from **Nagios** that **NGINX** down.

When I checked server - there was lot full swap and memory.

I found odd entries in log:

```
65.49.14.146 - - [04/Jan/2015:16:06:11 +0200] "GET /EC65E041-8DDF-D04A-8307-38506B99BE22/6C6CCDBA-AFF1-E54F-A6A6-0D7A76E35801/from HTTP/1.1" 404 11564 "http://domain.ua/lalala" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

What is is:

> EC65E041-8DDF-D04A-8307-38506B99BE22/6C6CCDBA-AFF1-E54F-A6A6-0D7A76E35801

I banned this IP on firewall, and LA and memory now looks good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL contains two UUID, but they probably don't mean anything.

Since the entries appear to be GET requests for a nonexisting URL there is little reason to think they could be causing any harm. If there are lots of them, then adding it all up, they could probably take some resources to process.

A decent server should be able to handle many requests triggering 404 every second. You haven't told us exactly how frequent those requests are. Assuming they are very frequent, then that in itself could explain slowdown on the server.

The IP address 65.49.14.146 belongs to Hurricane Electric. That is a respectable company. I suggest you ask them if blocking said IP could potentially block legitimate requests as well. They are usually very helpful.

Comment: Requesting missing page in **WordPress** by default causes search query in database, thus - it causes some load. I was too lazy, to disable it (but done now).